# How to know when all instances have been updated?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP bucket setup where I push my content files too and then have a flask app that pulls from the bucket and deploys. When I update the bucket there is at times a delay between it being updated in the bucket and updated on the live site. How can I tell when all instances have been updated?

Comment: Could you indicate 1) how you push the contents to Cloud Storage?, 2) What instances are being updated, GCE, GCF, ...?
3) Why do you need to know when they are updated?

Comment: The content is pushed via a pipeline on bitbucket. I believe all app engine instances are updated after a certain point. I want to know so I don't have to keep checking the site to see if the changes have been implemented.